# How to use interface methods randomly?

Tags: java, interface, random

I have an interface and these methods:

```
public interface Form {

public void setFirstName (String value);

public void setLastName (String value);

public void setGender (String value);
}
```

Can I call these methods randomly on an objet? Something like:

```
form.randomMethodFromFormInterface(String randomString);
```

Is it actually possible? Just to clarify, I would like to fillout the form randomly: sometimes just the last name, sometimes just the first name, sometimes just the gender.

Comment: Without the clarification, it looked like you were trying to confuse the developers using your API. I think it would be a good design practice to separate `randomMethodFromFormInterface` from the `Form` interface, as your second code snippet shows that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like below. However, I am not sure if I really like the idea of calling methods in an interface randomly. It breaks the contract in a way and sounds like a bad design idea in my opinion.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomInterfaceImpl implements RandomInterface {
    private Random rnd;
    public RandomInterfaceImpl(){
        rnd = new Random();
    }
    @Override
    public void setFirstName(String value) {
        System.out.println("called setFirstName");

    }

    @Override
    public void setLastName(String value) {
        System.out.println("called setLastName");

    }

    @Override
    public void setGender(String value) {
        System.out.println("called setGender");

    }

    @Override
    public void getNextRandomMethod(String value) {
        int nextRand = rnd.nextInt(3);
        switch(nextRand){
        case 0: setFirstName(value); break;
        case 1: setLastName(value); break;
        case 2: setGender(value); break;
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomInterface myInterface = new RandomInterfaceImpl();
        myInterface.getNextRandomMethod("Foo");
        myInterface.getNextRandomMethod("Foo");
        myInterface.getNextRandomMethod("Foo");
    }
```

prints:-

```
called setFirstName
called setLastName
called setLastName
```

Comment: @maerics if that is the intent then there should be a unit test case for each methods in the interface.

Answer (score 4):

```
Random rand = new Random();
switch (rand.nextInt(3)) {
  case 0: myForm.setFirstName(myFirstName); break;
  case 1: myForm.setLastName(myLastName); break;
  case 2: myForm.setGender(myGender); break;
  default: throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you use `Random` to pick from 0-2, and then depending on that value call the corresponding method?

Answer (score 2):

Could you make another method in the interface that generates a random number and calls a method based on that number? Although I would bet there's an easier way to do this than creating an interface for it.

Answer (score 2):

Here a general way, using reflection:

```
private static Random r = new Random();

public static void callRandomMethod(Object target, Class<?> iface, Object ... arguments) {
    List<Method> methods = findFittingMethods(iface, arguments);
    Method m = methods.get(r.nextInt(methods.size()));
    m.invoke(target, arguments);
}
public List<Method> findFittingMethods(Class<?> iface, Object ... arguments
    Method[] allMethods = iface.getMethods();
    List<Method> fittingMethods = new ArrayList<Method>();
    findMethodLoop:
    for(Method candidate : allMethods) {
        Class<?>[] argumentTypes = candidate.getArguments();
        if(argumentTypes.length != arguments.length) {
            continue;
        }
        // check argument types
        for(int i = 0; i < argumentTypes.length; i++) {
           if(arguments[i] == null) {
              if(argumentTypes[i].isPrimitive()) {
                 // null can't be passed to a primitive argument.
                 continue findMethodLoop;
              }
              else {
                 // ... but to every other argument type.
                 continue; // check next argument
              }
           }
           if(argumentTypes[i].isInstance(arguments[i])) {
               continue; // check next argument
           }
           if(argumentTypes[i].isPrimitive()) {
              // hack to check if we have the right wrapper class
              try {
                  Array.set(Array.newInstance(argumentTypes[i], 1), 0, arguments[i]);
                  continue; // check next argument
              }
              catch(ArrayStoreException ex) {
                  continue findMethodLoop;
              }
           }
           // wrong type
           continue findMethodLoop;
        }
        // now we found a method which would accept the arguments, put it into the list.
        fittingMethods.add(candidate);
    }
    return fittingMethods;
}
```

Of course, if you do this often, you would not create the list of methods for every call, but only once, and reuse it then. (And if you only have a known interface with a low number of methods, use the `switch` statement instead, like others have recommended.)

Answer (score 1):

You can place the various method names in an array structure.
Then choose a random index within the scope of the array.
Then use reflection to actually call the method using the randomly chosen name from the previous step

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the following method:

```
public static void randomMethodFromFormInterface(Form form, String value) {
    switch(random.nextInt(3) {
        case 0:
            form.setFirstName(value);
            break;
        case 1:
            form.setLastName(value);
            break;
        case 2:
            form.setGenderName(value);
            break;
    }
}
```

You can put it in a utility class. `random` here is, of course, an instance of `java.util.Random`.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I call these methods randomly on
>   an objet?

Yes, this is possible with Reflection. The randomness is not implemented in this example (I assume that you can easily do this with a random int) and all methods are called without knowing how they are named or how many methods are available. For simplicity the example assumes that the parameter is only a `String` (like in your example). Of course, you must instantiate a class which implements `Form`:

```
Class thisClass = Class.forName("FormImpl");
Object o = thisClass.newInstance();

Method[] methods = thisClass.getDeclaredMethods();
for(Method m : methods)
{
  m.invoke(o, "test");
}
```

Comment: This is not random right? You are invoking the methods iteratively in a predictive manner which is not random.

Comment: Yes, thats right. It's only an example to demonstrate Reflection. A `methods[rnd.nextInt(methods.size())].invoke(o, "test")` should be fairly easy.